# Not getting DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVE on Windows 7

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, windows-7

MSDN says that "The system broadcasts the `DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVE` device event to request permission to remove a device or piece of media."

On Windows XP its working fine but on Windows 7, my application is not getting `DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVE` event.

What is the issue?

Comment: It doesn't actually broadcast `DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVE`. It broadcasts the [`WM_DEVICECHANGE` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363480.aspx) to top-level windows with the `wParam` set to `DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVE`. That's not exactly the same thing. Which one are you listening for?

Comment: I am listening to WM_DEVICECHANGE with wParam DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVE. On Windows 7, application is not getting WM_DEVICECHANGE with wParam DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVE. On Windows XP its working. On Window 7 instead of DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVE,  DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE comes in wParam.